# OpenShift - nginx pod as SSL termination and load balancer

Tags: nginx, openshift, reverse-proxy, kubernetes-pod

In the past, I have used the following configuration file for `nginx` on Ubuntu. It does the following:

1. SSL termination
2. Load balancer
3. Inserts a custom header `X-Nginx-header`
4. Logs the invocations

```
events { }

http {
    log_format main '$time_iso8601 - $remote_addr - "$http_user_agent" - "$request" - $request_id '
    '- $status - $body_bytes_sent - $request_time ';

    access_log /home/ubuntu/project-demo/logs/access.log main;
    error_log /home/ubuntu/project-demo/logs/error.log error;
    proxy_cache_path /data/nginx/cache keys_zone=one:10m;

    upstream demoapp {
        least_conn;
        server localhost:3001;
        server localhost:3002;
        server localhost:3003;
        server localhost:3004;
    }

    server {
        listen 443 ssl;

        ssl_certificate         /home/ubuntu/project-demo/certs/server.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key     /home/ubuntu/project-demo/certs/server.pem;
        ssl_protocols           TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
        ssl_ciphers             HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
        ssl_session_cache       shared:SSL:20m;
        ssl_session_timeout     4h;

        location / {
            proxy_set_header X-Nginx-header $request_id;
            proxy_pass http://demoapp/;
        }
    }
}
```

I want to replicate the same with `nginx` deployed as a pod in an OpenShift cluster. I can see `nginx` as listed in the catalog of OpenShift cluster. When I try to launch one, it shows a field for GitHub repository with a sample repository - https://github.com/sclorg/nginx-ex.git

How do I utilize this repository for the configuration file shown above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation for the nginx 1.14 version of this image can be found [here](https://github.com/sclorg/nginx-container/tree/master/1.14)

This is an [s2i](https://github.com/openshift/source-to-image) image. s2i is a build mechanism that takes source code (in your case the nginx configuration) and a base s2i image (in your case the sclorg nginx contianer image) and produces a runtime image (in your case an nginx image with configuration).

Based on the above documentation for that nginx s2i image if you point the s2i build process at a VCS repository (or local directory) with any of the following files inside it, they will automatically be consumed by the nginx s2i builder image to produce a configured runtime container image.

```
./nginx.conf-- The main nginx configuration file

./nginx-cfg/*.conf
Should contain all nginx configuration we want to include into image

./nginx-default-cfg/*.conf
Contains any nginx config snippets to include in the default server block

./nginx-start/*.sh
Contains shell scripts that are sourced right before nginx is launched

./
Should contain nginx application source code
```

In your case that means you can either put your configuration in a `nginx.conf` file to overwrite the entire nginx configuration or in a `./nginx-cfg/*.conf` file to just add your configuration to the default nginx.conf file.

Comment: I started with `oc new-app centos/nginx-112-centos7~https://github.com/user/repo.git` where, the repo has `nginx.conf` at its root. However, I do not see it included in the pod and the pod is in running status forever with no logs.

Comment: What are the logs of the s2i build? The [assemble](https://github.com/sclorg/nginx-container/blob/master/1.14/s2i/bin/assemble#L9) script should output information during the build process letting you know whether or not it picked your file up. You should also be able to find the file inside the running container [here](https://github.com/sclorg/nginx-container/blob/master/1.14/Dockerfile#L38).

Comment: I am using a `nginx.conf` at the root folder as shown here - https://pastebin.com/yr0jNKyk . With the `new-app` command, the build logs (`oc logs -f bc/repo`) shows that the push is successful. The deployment does not seem to complete...

Comment: Looks like your runtime image is having trouble launching. First place I would check is whether nginx is starting in the runtime image and whether the configuration is good or not.

Comment: If you're deploying this inside OpenShift, the pod will have logs before it crashes. You can check inside the UI or via ```oc get logs <pod-id>```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200018/discussion-between-nick-and-cogitoergosum).