# nginx - Log format not applied in OpenShift pod

Tags: nginx, logging, openshift

Thanks to the answer from [Nick](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2394163/nick) on [running nginx pod as SSL termination end-point](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58100852/919480), I was able to run Nginx successfully on an OpenShift pod. However, I do not see the logs from this pod in a format as defined in this configuration file.

`nginx.conf`

```
events { }

http {
    log_format main '$time_iso8601 - $remote_addr - "$http_user_agent" - "$request" - $request_id '
    '- $status - $body_bytes_sent - $request_time ';

    upstream point1 {
        server point1-os.point1-os.svc:8080;
    }
    upstream point2 {
        server point2-os.point2-os.svc:8080;
    }

    server {
        listen 8080;
        location /point1/ {
            proxy_set_header X-Request-Id $request_id;
            proxy_pass http://point1/;
        }
        location /point2/ {
            proxy_set_header X-Request-Id $request_id;
            proxy_pass http://point2/;
        }        
    }
}
```

Instead, I see the logs as below:

```
172.17.0.1 - - [30/Sep/2019:23:48:02 +0530] "POST /point2/processes HTTP/1.1" 200 51 "-" "PostmanRuntime/7.17.1"
172.17.0.1 - - [30/Sep/2019:23:52:37 +0530] "GET /point2/process/resource1 HTTP/1.1" 400 223 "-" "PostmanRuntime/7.17.1"
172.17.0.1 - - [30/Sep/2019:23:53:11 +0530] "DELETE /point2/process/resource1 HTTP/1.1" 200 58 "-" "PostmanRuntime/7.17.1"
172.17.0.1 - - [30/Sep/2019:23:53:15 +0530] "GET /point2/process/resource1 HTTP/1.1" 200 66 "-" "PostmanRuntime/7.17.1"
```

Whereas, the expected log should have been in this order:

- Time stamp
- Remote address
- HTTP user agent e.g. `PostmanRuntime/7.17.1`
- Request verb e.g. `GET`, `POST`, etc.
- Request Id - automatically injected by Nginx - **not seen and critically required**
- Status
- Bytes sent
- Request time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're creating a `log_format` called `main`. You still need to *apply* that format to the access logs, something akin to the following should work

```
log_format main '$time_iso8601 - $remote_addr - "$http_user_agent" - "$request" - $request_id - $status - $body_bytes_sent - $request_time ';
access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log main;
```